# Multithreaded: translation in French

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique, anglicismes

Je désire rendre en français la phrase ci-après :

> Octave supports multi-threaded computation for a number of linear
>   algebra and element-wise numerical functions.

Dans la phrase ci-dessous :

> Octave soutient le calcul multithread pour un certain nombre d'algèbre
>   linéaire et fonctions numériques élément par élément.

peut-on garder le mot multithread ou existe-il un mot français adéquat ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Le multithread est une technique parmi plusieurs d'exécution parallèle. Si le terme est utilisé avec un sens technique précis, il peut être important de garder multithread. S'il est employé avec le sens général de calcul parallèle, on peut préférer ces termes plus généraux :

> Octave permet le calcul parallèle d'un certain nombre de fonctions numériques opérant en algèbre linéaire ou élément par élément.
>
> Octave parallélise le calcul d'un certain nombre de fonctions numériques, en algèbre linéaire et en calcul élément par élément.

Note sur la traduction :

- *Supports* a ici le sens d'*avoir une fonctionnalité* et pas de soutenir. Je préfère personnellement traduire par *permettre* ou utiliser une périphrase.
- Le texte source est ambigu mais à ma lecture un peu matheuse, ce qui est parallélisé, ce sont des fonctions de calcul numérique ; et ces fonctions numériques sont de deux types : opérations d'algèbre linéaire, et opérations élément par élément. Dans la question, c'est traduit comme si les choses parallelisées étaient d'une part les algèbres linéaires, d'autre part les fonctions de calcul numérique élément par élément. Les traductions ci-dessus utilisent ma lecture du texte.